# Implement Subtotal feature of Excel in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Excel provides the Subtotal option from the Menu Data -> Outline -> Subtotal.

[image] [image]

I want to implement this feature with Apache poi library in java. I implemented the code part which is creates excel file adds data but I can't find the way how to implement subtotal.  I researched but not found the solution. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know the subtotal-feature of Excel but it looks like a combination of grouping and sum-formulas, If this is the case you would use the `Sheet.groupRow()` to group the areas and create normal formula cells with a sum-formula.

Comment: Works with `Sheet.groupRow`. But instead `SUM` formulas `SUBTOTAL(9,...)` must be used.

Comment: @Lusi Have you found a solution to this problem? If yes, could you please answer your question or at least point to some link?